Python FastApi generated Swagger docs don't replace parameter placeholder (i.e. {id}) with value
i tried to create a fastapi router that would handle 2 path parameters of type int.
i expected it to replace the placeholders (i.e. {parameter_name}) with the value i entered in the swagger ui.
only one of the parameters were replaced, and the other was kept as the variable name with url encoded curly brackets, i.e. "%parameter_name%".
i defined this route with fastapi:
api_router = APIRouter(prefix="user/{user_id}")

@api_router.put("/post/{post_id}")
def module_deep_clone(
        user_id: int,
        post_id: int,
):
    return {"post_id": post_id, "company_id": company_id}


Using the generated Swagger ui results in a bad request url, where one path variable isn't replaced with the value:
"http://0.0.0.0:8000/user/123/post/{post_id}"
which results in a validation error, as post_id is expected to be an integer and not "%7Bpost_id%"
when i replace the order of parameter definition in the function:
@api_router.put("/post/{post_id}")
def module_deep_clone(
        post_id: int,
        user_id: int,
):

the resulting url is:
"http://0.0.0.0:8000/user/{user_id}/post/123"
which made me think that somehow Swagger was expecting only one parameter, but the relevant section in the resulting openapi.json looks like this:
"parameters": [
        {
            "name": "company_id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
                "type": "integer",
                "title": "Company Id"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "item_id",
            "in": "path",
            "required": true,
            "schema": {
                "type": "integer",
                "title": "Item Id"
            }
        }
    ]}

i'm using python 3.11, fastapi 0.101.1.
What am i missing?
Thanks

This is a bug in latest version of Swagger UI.
You can overcome it by using older version (https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi/discussions/11572#discussioncomment-9403528) :
app = FastAPI(docs_url=None)  # Disable default docs

from fastapi.openapi.docs import (get_swagger_ui_html,
                                  get_swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_html)

@app.get("/docs", include_in_schema=False)
async def custom_swagger_ui_html():
    return get_swagger_ui_html(
        openapi_url=app.openapi_url,
        title=app.title + " - Swagger UI",
        oauth2_redirect_url=app.swagger_ui_oauth2_redirect_url,
        swagger_js_url="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5.9.0/swagger-ui-bundle.js",
        swagger_css_url="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@5.9.0/swagger-ui.css",
    )


Seems like the fix has already been released, but I haven't checked: https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues/9928
